# Developing a bot

Tags: bots, speech-to-text, intentservice

I need to build a bot and I would like to ask how to start such a task.

My understanding is I need a framework that provides speech to text.

Then I need to generate *intents* from the text. Then use my algorithm to figure out what to do and response.

Can you please help me by directing me to which frameworks to look for the 2 purposes I mentioned?

Thank you

Comment: you can find a lot of framework to do that in a lot of langage

By what you say, you want to build a bot with speech recognition, right? You have a lot of them in Python, but you can 'cheat' and use Google API to do so too

Comment: Hi @sheplu, I am comfortable with java and python, can you recommend anything specific? Google's API provides the intents, right? Why is it a 'cheat'?

Comment: I think one of the best in python is this one https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/

Comment: @sheplu was talking about Google Speech API (https://cloud.google.com/speech/) which is not free for more than 60mn/month. 'Cheat' because you don't have to write your own framework ;)

Comment: @fandango yep exactly :D i forget to edit my comment to add this. thx !

Comment: Thank you. What about generating intents once I have the text?

Answer (score 1):

SpeechRecognition is a good option !

**Here's a working code :**

```
 import speech_recognition as sr  

 # obtain audio from the microphone  
 r = sr.Recognizer()  
 with sr.Microphone() as source:  
   print("Please wait. Calibrating microphone...")  
   # listen for 5 seconds and create the ambient noise energy level  
   r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=5)  
   print("Say something!")  
   audio = r.listen(source)  

 # recognize speech using Sphinx  
 try:  
   print("Sphinx thinks you said '" + r.recognize_sphinx(audio) + "'")  
 except sr.UnknownValueError:  
   print("Sphinx could not understand audio")  
 except sr.RequestError as e:  
   print("Sphinx error; {0}".format(e))
```

Other than the above, I found a niche script that allows you to ***run your own*** **telegram-bot**

```
// Telegram bot
// which converts given voice(speech) to text
// using wit.ai HTTP API
//
// meinside@gmail.com
//
// last update: 2016.05.17.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/exec"

    bot "github.com/meinside/telegram-bot-go"
    witai "github.com/meinside/wit.ai-go"
)

const (
    TelegramApiToken = "01234567:abcdefghijklmn_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST" // XXX - Edit this value to yours
    WitaiApiToken    = "01234567ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST"                 // XXX - Edit this value to yours

    MonitorIntervalSeconds = 1
    Verbose                = false // XXX - set this to 'true' for verbose messages

    TempDir       = "/tmp"                  // XXX - Edit this value to yours
    FfmpegBinPath = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg" // XXX - Edit this value to yours
)

// Download given url and return the downloaded path
func downloadFile(url string) (filepath string, err error) {
    log.Printf("> downloading voice file: %s\n", url)

    var file *os.File
    if file, err = ioutil.TempFile(TempDir, "downloaded_"); err == nil {
        filepath = file.Name()

        defer file.Close()

        var response *http.Response
        if response, err = http.Get(url); err == nil {
            defer response.Body.Close()

            if _, err = io.Copy(file, response.Body); err == nil {
                log.Printf("> finished downloading voice file: %s\n", filepath)
            }
        }
    }

    return filepath, err
}

// Convert .ogg to .mp3 (using ffmpeg)
//
// NOTE: wit.ai doesn't support stereo sound for now
// (https://wit.ai/docs/http/20160516#post--speech-link)
func oggToMp3(oggFilepath string) (mp3Filepath string, err error) {
    mp3Filepath = fmt.Sprintf("%s.mp3", oggFilepath)

    // $ ffmpeg -i input.ogg -ac 1 output.mp3
    params := []string{"-i", oggFilepath, "-ac", "1", mp3Filepath}
    cmd := exec.Command("ffmpeg", params...)

    if _, err = cmd.CombinedOutput(); err != nil {
        mp3Filepath = ""
    }

    return mp3Filepath, err
}

// Download a file from given url and convert it to a text.
//
// Downloaded or converted files will be deleted automatically.
func speechToText(w *witai.Client, fileUrl string) (text string, err error) {
    var oggFilepath, mp3Filepath string

    // download .ogg,
    if oggFilepath, err = downloadFile(fileUrl); err == nil {
        // .ogg => .mp3,
        if mp3Filepath, err = oggToMp3(oggFilepath); err == nil {
            // .mp3 => text
            if result, err := w.QuerySpeechMp3(mp3Filepath, nil, "", "", 1); err == nil {
                log.Printf("> analyzed speech result: %+v\n", result)

                if result.Text != nil {
                    text = fmt.Sprintf("\"%s\"", *result.Text)

                    /*
                        // traverse for more info
                        sessionId := "01234567890abcdef"
                        if results, err := w.ConverseAll(sessionId, *result.Text, nil); err == nil {
                            for i, r := range results {
                                log.Printf("> converse[%d] result: %v\n", i, r)
                            }
                        } else {
                            log.Printf("failed to converse: %s\n", err)
                        }
                    */
                }
            }

            // delete converted file
            if err = os.Remove(mp3Filepath); err != nil {
                log.Printf("*** failed to delete converted file: %s\n", mp3Filepath)
            }
        } else {
            log.Printf("*** failed to convert .ogg to .mp3: %s\n", err)
        }

        // delete downloaded file
        if err = os.Remove(oggFilepath); err != nil {
            log.Printf("*** failed to delete downloaded file: %s\n", oggFilepath)
        }
    }

    return text, err
}

func main() {
    b := bot.NewClient(TelegramApiToken)
    b.Verbose = Verbose

    w := witai.NewClient(WitaiApiToken)
    w.Verbose = Verbose

    if unhooked := b.DeleteWebhook(); unhooked.Ok { // delete webhook
        // wait for new updates
        b.StartMonitoringUpdates(0, MonitorIntervalSeconds, func(b *bot.Bot, u bot.Update, err error) {
            if err == nil && u.HasMessage() {
                b.SendChatAction(u.Message.Chat.Id, bot.ChatActionTyping) // typing...

                if u.Message.HasVoice() { // when voice is received,
                    if sent := b.GetFile(u.Message.Voice.FileId); sent.Ok {
                        if message, err := speechToText(w, b.GetFileUrl(*sent.Result)); err == nil {
                            if len(message) <= 0 {
                                message = "Failed to analyze your voice."
                            }
                            if sent := b.SendMessage(u.Message.Chat.Id, &message, map[string]interface{}{}); !sent.Ok {
                                log.Printf("*** failed to send message: %s\n", *sent.Description)
                            }
                        } else {

                            message := fmt.Sprintf("Failed to analyze your voice: %s", err)
                            if sent := b.SendMessage(u.Message.Chat.Id, &message, map[string]interface{}{}); !sent.Ok {
                                log.Printf("*** failed to send message: %s\n", *sent.Description)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else { // otherwise,
                    message := "Let me hear your voice."
                    if sent := b.SendMessage(u.Message.Chat.Id, &message, map[string]interface{}{}); !sent.Ok {
                        log.Printf("*** failed to send message: %s\n", *sent.Description)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    } else {
        panic("failed to delete webhook")
    }
}
```

> $ wget
>   https://gist.githubusercontent.com/meinside/56f2616c61f59768b4ce487bea4f9fd5/raw/e9984ec1ac46a47d1b7b5ccf1a178147588c3552/stt_bot_sample.go

Run your edited code:

```
$ go run stt_bot_sample.go
```

[Bot in Action ! (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GR95O.png)